# Write a package that is aware of the mainlanguage selected in babel or polyglossia

Tags: babel, package-writing, polyglossia

How can I make my package aware of the language choosen with `babel` or `polyglossia`, so that some auto-generated strings can be generated in respect to the current language?

As an example, I have a macro `\my@string` that shall expand to “Caption” in english text, “Überschrift” in german text, or “titre” in french ones.

Comment: If you can read German: I wrote a blog post about this a while ago on texwelt.de: [Internationalisierung oder: wie stelle ich Übersetzungen in meinem Paket bereit?](http://texwelt.de/blog/internationalisierung-oder-wie-stelle-ich-ubersetzungen-in-meinem-paket-bereit/)

Comment: Yeah, I am able to read german, much better than english :D Thanks for answer and link, I'll give it a deeper look this evening.

Comment: I know this question is old, but if anyone's interested I wrote a related article in TUGBoat: [Localisation of TeX documents: tracklang](http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-3/tb117talbot.pdf).

Comment: @clemens Guter Artikel!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are several possibilities. I'll present four different ways. The first two use directly or indirectly the macros `\captions<lang>` or `\extras<lang>` which are provided both by `babel` and `polyglossia`. `babel` says the following about those two:

- `\captions<lang>` : The macro `\captions<lang>` defines the macros that hold the texts to replace the original hard-wired texts.
- `\extras<lang>` : The macro `\extras<lang>` contains all the extra definitions needed for a specific language. This macro [...] is a hook – you can add things to it, but it must not be used directly.

the `babel` manual uses `\extras<lang>` for examples of user defined definitions for the language `<lang>`. The main difference to `\captions<lang>` from a user perspective is that `\extras<lang>` is set later. So if both define the same macro for a language the definition in `\extras<lang>` »wins«.

### `\addto\captions<...>`

You can check if `babel` or `polyglossia` have been loaded and if they are add the translations to `\captions<lang>` or `\extras<lang>`:

```
\newcommand*\mytitle{Title}
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}
  {\addto\captionsngerman{\def\mytitle{Titel}}}
  {
    \@ifpackageloaded{polyglossia}
      {\addto\captionsngerman{\def\mytitle{Titel}}}
      {}
  }
```

This could be wrapped up in a more convenient conditional, of course, in order not to have to duplicate code.

This is an expandable solution which means that `\mytitle` can also be used in PDF bookmarks or other places where this is useful.

A possible drawback: with this solution you have to provide translations for each »dialect«. For example if you set `\addto\captionsngerman` but a user chooses the language `german` he won't see the translation.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mypackage.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2014/07/27 v0.0 my new package]

\newcommand*\iflanguagepackage[1]{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{babel}
    {#1}
    {%
      \@ifpackageloaded{polyglossia}
        {#1}
        {}%
    }%
}

\newcommand*\mytitle{Title}
\iflanguagepackage{%
  \addto\captionsenglish{\def\mytitle{Title}}%
  \addto\captionsngerman{\def\mytitle{Titel}}%
  \addto\captionsfrench{\def\mytitle{Titre}}%
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\begin{document}

\mytitle

\selectlanguage{french}
\mytitle

\selectlanguage{english}
\mytitle

\end{document}
```

### `scrbase`

The [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes or more precisely the KOMA-Script support package `scrbase` provides `\providecaptionname`. With this macro you don't have to check for the language packages. Otherwise it is pretty much the same:

```
\newcommand*\mytitle{Title}
\providecaptionname{ngerman}\mytitle{Titel}
```

It has the same advantages and drawbacks as the first solution (expandability, dialects, ...).

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mypackage.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2014/07/27 v0.0 my new package]
\RequirePackage{scrbase}

\newcommand*\mytitle{Title}
\providecaptionname{english}\mytitle{Title}
\providecaptionname{ngerman}\mytitle{Titel}
\providecaptionname{french}\mytitle{Titre}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\begin{document}

\mytitle

\selectlanguage{french}
\mytitle

\selectlanguage{english}
\mytitle

\end{document}
```

It has advantages over the pure `babel`/`polyglossia` way, though: for one thing the first argument of `\providecaptionname` can be a comma separated list of languages so it is more convenient to provide translations for dialects or language aliases. Also there are a number of related commands that allow finer control:

- `\defcaptionname{<list of languages>}{<macro>}{<translation>}`: define the translation no matter what. (Like `\def`)
- `\providecaptionname{<list of languages>}{<macro>}{<translation>}`: define a caption name for a language in `<list of languages>` if there isn't one, yet. (Like `\providecommand`)
- `\newcaptionname{<list of languages>}{<macro>}{<translation>}`: define a caption name for a language in `<list of languages>` if there isn't one, yet, throw an error otherwise. (like `\newcommand`)
- `\renewcaptionname{<list of languages>}{<macro>}{<translation>}`: renew an existing caption name for a language in `<list of languages>`. If there isn't one, yet, throw an error. (like `\renewcommand`)

Those commands decide themselves if it is better to add the translations to `\captions<lang>` or `\extras<lang>` except if you use their starred variants which will always use `\extras<lang>`. With v3.12 those macros defer the definitions at begin document.

### `translator`

The `translator` package (part of [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/beamer)) is a more general solution.

The `beamer` manual says this:

> The `translator` package is a LaTeX package that provides a flexible
>   mechanism for translating individual words into different languages.
>   For example, it can be used to translate a word like “figure” into,
>   say, the German word “Abbildung”. Such a translation mechanism is
>   useful when the author of some package would like to localize the
>   package such that texts are correctly translated into the language
>   preferred by the user. The `translator` package is not intended to be
>   used to automatically translate more than a few words.
>
> You may wonder
>   whether the `translator` package is really necessary since there is the
>   (very nice) `babel` package available for LaTeX. This package already
>   provides translations for words like “figure”. Unfortunately, the
>   architecture of the `babel` package was designed in such a way that
>   there is no way of adding translations of new words to the (very
>   short) list of translations directly built into `babel`.

Although we know now this is not entirely true the `translator` package is nevertheless a very useful generalization. The basic usage is as follows:

```
\newcommand*\mytitle{\translate{mypackage-title}}
\newtranslation[to=English]{mypackage-title}{Title}
\newtranslation[to=German]{mypackage-title}{Titel}
```

With it you also don't have to check for `babel` or `polyglossia` yourself. However, for the translating to work correctly the `translator` package needs to get the used language as package option which means a user should use the language as global option:

```
\documentclass[german]{article}
\usepackage{mypackage}
```

So a package using it should probably tell users about this. On the plus side: `\newtranslation[to=German]` works for `german` and `ngerman` automatically. If a language is used where no translation is given the English translation is used as fallback.

On the minus side: `\translate` is not expandable which might or might not cause trouble (e.g. when used in a `\section` and `hyperref` is used for PDF bookmarks).

One other possible advantage: it comes with dictionaries which already provide quite a number of translations.

Besides `\newtranslation` `translator` provides a number of similar commands:

- `\deftranslation[to=<lang>]{<string>}{<translation>}` : provide a new translation to `<string>` for language `<lang>` no matter what. (like `\def`)
- `\newtranslation[to=<lang>]{<string>}{<translation>}` : provide a new translation to `<string>` for language `<lang>`. Throw an error if it already exists. (like `\newcommand`)
- `\providetranslation[to=<lang>]{<string>}{<translation>}` : provide a new translation to `<string>` for language `<lang>` if it doesn't exist, yet. (like `\providecommand`)
- `\renewtranslation[to=<lang>]{<string>}{<translation>}` : renew an existing translation to `<string>` for language `<lang>`. Throw an error if it doesn't exist, yet. (like `\renewcommand`)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mypackage.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2014/07/27 v0.0 my new package]
\RequirePackage{translator}

\newcommand*\mytitle{\translate{mypackage-title}}
\newtranslation[to=English]{mypackage-title}{Title}
\newtranslation[to=German]{mypackage-title}{Titel}
\newtranslation[to=French]{mypackage-title}{Titre}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[english,french,ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\begin{document}

\mytitle

\selectlanguage{french}
\mytitle

\selectlanguage{english}
\mytitle

\end{document}
```

### `translations`

You might also want to have a look at the [`translations`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/translations) package.

It's usage is very similar to `translator`. It has a few advantages, though:

- its `\GetTranslation` is expandable
- the chosen language is recognized also if not given as global option
- it knows the concept of dialects

From the manual:

> This package provides means for package authors to have an easy
>   interface for internationalization of their packages. The
>   functionality of this package is in many parts also covered by the
>   package `translator` (part of the `beamer` bundle).
>   Internationalization is also possible with `babel` and it’s
>   `\addto\captions<language>` mechanism or KOMA-Script's
>   `\providecaptionname` and similar commands. However, I believe that
>   `translations` is more flexible than all of these. Unlike `translator` it
>   detects the used (`babel` or `polyglossia`) language itself and
>   provides expandable retrieving of the translated key. `translations`
>   also provides support for language dialects which means package
>   authors can for example distinguish between British, Australian,
>   Canadian and US English.

`translations` provides a number of macros for defining and retrieving translated strings. Most of the times

- `\DeclareTranslationFallback{<string>}{<translation>}` ,
- `\DeclareTranslation{<language>}{<string>}{<translation>}` and
- `\GetTranslation{<string>}`

will suffice, though.

There are also

- `\NewTranslation{<language>}{<string>}{<translation>}` ,
- `\ProvideTranslation{<language>}{<string>}{<translation>}` and
- `\RenewTranslation{<language>}{<string>}{<translation>}`

with the same consequences as mentioned for `scrbase`'s and `translator`'s macros.

Each string should at least have a »fallback translation« which is used whenever no language package is present or the user has chosen a language for which no translation has been provided.

Like the `translator` package `translations` also knows dictionaries and already provides a number of translations.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mypackage.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2014/07/27 v0.0 my new package]
\RequirePackage{translations}

\newcommand*\mytitle{\GetTranslation{mypackage-title}}

% translations for `mypackage-title':
\DeclareTranslationFallback {mypackage-title}{Title}
\DeclareTranslation{English}{mypackage-title}{Title}
\DeclareTranslation{French} {mypackage-title}{Titre}
\DeclareTranslation{German} {mypackage-title}{Titel}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english,french,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mypackage}
\begin{document}

\mytitle

\selectlanguage{french}
\mytitle

\selectlanguage{english}
\mytitle

\end{document}
```

All complete examples give

[image]

Comment: Thank you, `translations` seems to do it job very well since it does not depend on global options or koma-stuff (even if I primarily use KOMA, there might be persons or institutions who/which decline to use it, as my university does)

Comment: I use `translations` quite a lot in my packages myself. However, since it's easy to load `scrbase` independently (as I've shown in the example above) none of the four solutions depend on a KOMA class!

Comment: But it depends on scrbase, which is forbidden at my university as part of KOMA-script. I really don't know why, and I won't start a discussion about that topic, many have tried before and all have lost.

Comment: In that case you can't use `translations` either since it loads the KOMA package `scrlfile`. Does that mean you have to check `\listfiles` every time in order to make sure that no KOMA package has been loaded? I can't believe that!

Comment: There are quite a number of KOMA packages that could be loaded by other packages, too: `scrbase`, `scrlfile`, `scrrfile`, `tocbasic`, `scrhack` ...

Comment: Hmph… If KOMA is so deeply involved in everything, I think I have to go through that discussion right again, especially since I just found out, that there is `scrbase` and `scrhack` in the `\listfiles` of the official thesis template :) Thanks for the hint!

Comment: @NobbZ Offtopic, but i just need to ask: Which university sets those restraints?

Comment: Until a decission is made if that constraint will be cancelled or not, I refuse to go into detail