# Difference between \addto\captions<languague> and \addto\extras<languague> in babel

Tags: babel, package-writing

---

What I (hopefully) understood:

---

I'm getting a bit into Babel for my Lieder-Package. I want to support all 70 languages listed [here](https://tug.org/pracjourn/2007-1/gregorio/gregorio.pdf).

As far as I understood I can do this ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193448/write-a-package-that-is-aware-of-the-mainlanguage-selected-in-babel-or-polygloss)):

```
\newcommand*\GFMlistOfSongs{List of Songs}
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}
  {
  \addto\captionsngerman{\def\GFMlistOfSongs{Liederverzeichnis}}
  \addto\captionsgerman{\def\GFMlistOfSongs{Liederr Verrrzaichniss}}
  \addto\captionsfoospeak{\def\GFMlistOfSongs{lista di songos}}
  }
  
\def\createLOS{
  \GFMlistOfSongs \\ \BoDY % BoDY = somewhere else defined.
}

\begin{document}
\createLOS
\end{document}
```

which will create some list with the list title in the correct language.

---

What I don't understand:

---

I saw `\addto\extras<lang.>` several times. What is the difference between that and `\addto\captions<lang.>`?

I had a look into the babel docu, but haven't found anything.

Comment: Extras are evaluated at each language change; captions aren't within `otherlanguage*` and `\foreignlanguage`. Typically, list names go in captions.

Comment: @egreg Ok, extras at language change. Are `extrasngerman` evaluated when the change is from `ngerman` or to `ngerman`? What do you mean by "captions aren't used". I would suppose, that inside `otherlanguage*` the captions of the other language are used. i.e. `language=ngerman`, `otherlanguage=foospeak`will result in `lista di songos` inside `otherlanguage`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are basically five ways to change the current language:

1. `\selectlanguage{<language>}`
2. `\begin{otherlanguage}{<language>}...\end{otherlanguage}`
3. `\begin{otherlanguage*}{<language>}...\end{otherlanguage*}`
4. `\foreignlanguage{<language>}{...}`
5. `\begin{hyphenrules}{<language>}...\end{hyphenrules}`

The difference between 1 and 2 is that in the second case you don't need to change back the language. The difference between 3 and 4 is that method 3 is better for multiparagraph text and 4 is for small phrases inside a paragraph.

With methods 1 and 2, both `\captions<language>` and `\extras<language>` are performed; with methods 3 and 4 only `\extras<language>` is performed. With method 5 only the hyphenation rules change, and neither `\captions<language>` nor `\extras<language>` is performed.

Indeed, tags such as `\figurename` are in `\captions<language>`, whereas language specific features are in `\extras<language>`.

<sub>If you add something to `\extras<language>`, the corresponding “reverse setting” should be added to `\noextras<language>`, which is performed at the next `\selectlanguage` command.</sub>

For instance, in Italian the apostrophe should have a nonzero `\lccode` in order for hyphenation to work correctly; so the setting `` \lccode`\'=`\' `` is part of `\extrasitalian`. Similarly, language shorthands should be in `\extras<language>`.

Your code for localizing lists of songs should definitely go in `\captions<language>`:

```
\newcommand*\GFMlistOfSongs{List of Songs}

\@ifpackageloaded{babel}
  {%
  \addto\captionsngerman{\def\GFMlistOfSongs{Liederverzeichnis}}%
  \addto\captionsgerman{\def\GFMlistOfSongs{Liederr Verrrzaichniss}}%
  \addto\captionsfoospeak{\def\GFMlistOfSongs{lista di songos}}%
  }{}

\def\createLOS{%
  \GFMlistOfSongs \\ \BoDY % BoDY = somewhere else defined.
}
```

(don't forget the terminating `%` and the empty third argument to `\@ifpackageloaded`).