# translator and translations packages: Pros and Cons?

Tags: translator, translations

Since some time I am working to a quite peculiar `bash-TeX` project and at some point I needed to provide multilingual support. New to the problem, I looked quickly around for an easy solution and I decided to use the [`translations`](https://ctan.org/pkg/translations) package. My need was to have a set of expressions available in a bunch of languages as well as a pair of commands: one to get the translation and one other to get the translation as well, but with the initial letter capitalised. In a probably too naive way, I made the unlucky choice to call my commands simply `\translate` and `\Translate`, respectively. This resulted in a conflict later if the [`translator`](https://ctan.org/pkg/translator) package was loaded by some other package (e.g. `siunitx`). Clearly, choosing a better name for my commands (like using an appropriate prefix) would straightforwardly solve my issue. Nevertheless, the inclination to improve and learn made me read the `translator` documentation in order to see if, by chance, it was a better suited package for my use case. Since I could not really remark fundamental differences, I hand over the question about pros and cons of the two packages. In particular, when should one be preferred to the other? Is it just matter of taste?

As add-on, I have a further curiosity. Is there a direct way to check if a translation is available with the `translator` package? Said differently, which is the equivalent of the `\IfTranslation` command of the `translations` package? From the `translator` [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/translator/translator.pdf) (subsection 1.3.5), it is clear that if a translation is not available, the `<key>` itself is used. So if I had to write myself an `\IfTranslation` command I would take advantage of this fact comparing the translation of a `<key>` with the `<key>` itself. Is it a wise approach?

Comment: Have you read https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193452/

Comment: Well, now yes! :) It adds some information and it also kind of confirms my initial feeling about the fact that the `translations` package looks more complete. The fact that `\GetTranslation` is expandable and that `\translate` is not could play a role in the decision between the two. Still, my curiosity remains unanswered. ;)