# How to create a class that changes the word "Theorem" according to some chosen language as input?

Tags: document-classes, amsthm, package-writing

I'm having some problems on creating a class that changes the word "Definition" in `\begin{definition}` according to a chosen language. For simplicity I will consider only the English language

The class file `myreport.cls`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesClass{myreport}

\RequirePackage{changelang}

\DeclareOption{eng}{
  \PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{changelang}
}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, notitlepage]{extreport} 

\endinput
```

The file `changelang.sty`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesPackage{changelang}

\RequirePackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm} 

\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc} % output

%% language options
\DeclareOption{eng}{
    \theoremstyle{definition}
    \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
    \providecommand*{\definitionautorefname}{Definition}    
}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\endinput
```

Now when I try to use `\begin{definition}` in the main document after choosing `\documentclass[eng]{myreport}`, I get the complaint that it's undefined. Any ideas on how to correct that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use `\newtheorem{defi}`, therefore you should use `\begin{defi}` and not `\begin{definition}`. Also the MWE doesn't work because you load the `extreport` class after the `changelang` package, therefore when you load the package the `section` counter is not defined yet, resulting in an error.

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for the correction. That was a typo. Regarding your second point. I've tried loading it before processing the options in the cls file and also in the sty file. No luck yet. `begin{definition}` still undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure this is the first error you get, or are there any other errors before? Set your editor or terminal command to `halt-on-error` to make sure LaTeX stops at the very first error that is encountered. I tested your MWE and by loading the `extreport` class directly after `\ProvidesClass{myreport}` and fixing the typo for definition it worked without a problem.

Comment: you don't (normally) want to declare the whole environment in the option handler, all the standard fixed texts use a `\...name` convention so declare your environment using `\definitionname` rather than `Definition` then define `\definitionname` to be `Definition`  with language options giving suitable translations. see `\chaptername`, `\contentsname`,  `\figurename` etc

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/193448/

Comment: @Marijn That seems to be the first error. I've checked the log too.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you mean something like    `\let\definame{\detokenize{Definition}}` inside the `\DeclareOption{eng}`, `\theoremstyle` before `ProcessOptions` and `\newtheorem` and `\providecommand*` after everything? If so, it's not working. By the way, is this `\...name` created by default from `\theoremstyle`? Where can I read more about this `\...name` thing?

Comment: @Marijn Also I'm using LuaLaTeX, but I've tried with XeLaTeX too.

Comment: `\let\definame{` would define `\definame`  to be `{` and `\detokenize` does nothing. Simply `\renewcommand\definame{Definition}` and use `\newtheorem{definition}{\definitionname}[section]`  look in book.cls at `\chaptername`, `\figurename` etc. That is how `babel` translates all the fixed texts to each language. It does not have to redefine caption and heading layout just redefine the text strings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the reply. It's working now. My bad. In my previous comment it should be `\edef` instead of `\let` and `\newtheorem` instead of `\theoremstyle` when I asked whether it would create `\...name` by default. Also I had to load the class before `RequirePackage{changelang}`, which is weird since the options are processed later anyway... I'm still curious why I can't define a new environment inside `DeclareOption`...

Comment: you can declare a new environment in the option handler it is just rather unusual to do so, and a major part of the design of latex2e (over the previous latex2.09) was to pull all fixed strings out to simple `\xxxname` macros so that language customisation would not need to re-do complicated layout definitions, and simply supply localised versions of the strings