Multilingual Theorem Style Settings .sty Not Functioning
I'm working on my LaTeX template (XeLaTeX). Since I work on documents in with multiple languages, I want to make a .sty set-theorems so that I can use different theorem style settings in different languages with a single argument, i.e. \usepackage[zh]{set-theorems} ...etc. But when I include my .sty in my main .tex file, I always get english theorem names no matter what is the option.
What is the problem with my code? Is this a problem with the code itself, or it has something to do with the compiling settings? I would like a solution that is robust, and would not be affected by polyglossia, babel or other language settings related packages.
Generally, is this practice of writing .sty for multilingual purposes good? or I should let some language settings package do its job? (but in my memory I don't recall some packages that do this)
set-theorems.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{set-theorems}[2024/12/26 v1.0 Theorem Style Settings]

\RequirePackage{amsthm}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\mytheoremLang{en} % \newcommand\mytheoremLang{} gives the same result

\DeclareOption{en}{\renewcommand\mytheoremLang{en}}
\DeclareOption{de}{\renewcommand\mytheoremLang{de}}
\DeclareOption{zh}{\renewcommand\mytheoremLang{zh}}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\ifstrequal{\mytheoremLang}{en}{
  \def\theoremname{Theorem}
  \def\lemmaname{Lemma}
  % ... more
}{
  \ifstrequal{\mytheoremLang}{zh}{
    \def\theoremname{定理}
    \def\lemmaname{引理}
    % ... more
  }{
    \ifstrequal{\mytheoremLang}{de}{
      \def\theoremname{Satz}
      \def\lemmaname{Lemma}
      % ... more
    }{
      \def\theoremname{Theorem}
      \def\lemmaname{Lemma}
      % ... more
    }
  }
}

\newtheorem{thm}{\theoremname}
\newtheorem{lm}{\lemmaname}

(minimal) main.tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\usepackage[zh]{set-theorems}


\begin{document}
 \begin{thm}
  測試定理
 \end{thm}
 \begin{lm}
  測試引理
 \end{lm}
\end{document}


I'm not sure ifstrequal actually expands its arguments. I would use expl3 instead. It has a super nice str_cases construct, so you Don need these nested ifs . See interface3.pdf for details.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642627/how-to-create-a-class-that-changes-the-word-theorem-according-to-some-chosen-l/729218

Consider switching to LuaLaTeX. See: https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2144
