# Setting up a translatable package

Tags: packages, package-writing, package-options, locale

I maintain a LaTeX package that produces an output with three English words: “and”, “p.” and “pp.”. I would like that if someone used my package in a German document these three strings automatically became “und”, “S.” and “S.”

What is the most widespread practice for setting up internationalization support in a LaTeX package? I will not be the one translating these strings into every single language, but I do want to make my package *translatable*.

If it was a software package this would be easily done by the ubiquitous GNU gettext. Is there some sort of “LaTeX gettext”?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193452/208544

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `translator` package. It already contains translations of many terms, like `and`, `Page` or `Pages`, but you can also add missing terms yourself:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{report}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{translator}
\usedictionary{translator-basic-dictionary}

\deftranslation[to=German]{p.}{\translate{S.}}
\deftranslation[to=German]{pp.}{\translate{S.}}

\begin{document}

\translate{and}

\translate{Page}

\translate{Pages}

\translate{p.}

\translate{pp.}

\end{document}
```